# Automapper Property Validation on Conditional Object Mapper

Tags: automapper

I'm using AutoMapper and the Conditional Mapper I've configured below seems to be working properly, but I can't figure out how to turn off validation on it (e.g. `MemberList.None`) like in the explicit `CreateMap` call below it.

```
public static void Configure(IMapperConfigurationExpression cfg) {
  // I want to put a MemberList.None on this
  cfg.AddConditionalObjectMapper().Where((s, d) => {
    return s == typeof(BusinessObjects.Tab) &&
    d.Namespace == "DocuSign.eSign.Model" && //is in model namespace
    d.GetMembers().FirstOrDefault(m => m.Name == "TabId") != null; //has a property TabId makes it a DocuSign Tab object
  });

  cfg.CreateMap<BusinessObjects.RequestModels.SigningEnvelope, ds.EnvelopeDefinition>(MemberList.Source);
}
```

Came up with this rough equivalent for the time being. Would still like to know if there's a way to achieve this with the `AddConditionalObjectMapper` method.

```
var tabTypes = Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(ds.EnvelopeDefinition)).GetTypes()
  .Where(t => t.Namespace == "DocuSign.eSign.Model" && 
    t.GetMembers().Any(m => m.Name == "TabId"));

foreach (var tt in tabTypes) {
  cfg.CreateMap(typeof(BusinessObjects.Tab), tt, MemberList.None);
}
```

Comment: https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/blob/08fa99f3ec8d2c3a1b312d6b76d6c42eced7bac2/src/UnitTests/ConvensionTest.cs#L148

Answer (score 0, accepted):

H/T to [Lucian](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1811700/lucian-bargaoanu) for pointing me towards the answer.

There's an instance method on the Automapper Profile class called `ForAllMaps` which lets you iterate over the conditionally created maps. So I created a new class inheriting from `Profile` and was able to achieve my original goal with the snippet below.

```
public class DocuSignTabsMappingConfiguration: Profile {
  public DocuSignTabsMappingConfiguration() {
    AddConditionalObjectMapper()
      .Where((s, d) => {
        return s == typeof(BusinessObjects.Tab) &&
        d.Namespace == "DocuSign.eSign.Model" &&
        d.GetMembers().FirstOrDefault(m => m.Name == "TabId") != null;
      });

    ForAllMaps((tm, exp) => exp.ValidateMemberList(MemberList.None));
  }
}
```

And in my primary Mapper configuration, replaced my old block of code with:

```
cfg.AddProfile(typeof(DocuSignTabsMappingConfiguration));
```